# Calling a C++ function using function pointer

Tags: c++, c, mfc

I have a function that receive a function pointer and an **XML** string which has the defination of the function and the argument per say:

```
void CallFunction( void * pFuncion, std::string xmlFuncionDef)
{

}
```

Inside the above function, `xmlFunctionDef` contains the definition of the function pointed by `pFunction`. For example, number parameter, type of each parameter, and the arguments:

```
<Function ParamCount="3" ReturnType="int">
  <Params>
    <Param type="int" DefaultValue="None" PassBy="Value"/>
    <Param type="double" DefaultValue="None" PassBy="Referenc"/>
    <Param type="char*" DefaultValue="None" PassBy="Pointer"/>
  </Params>

  <Arguments>
   <Arg Value="3" />
   <Arg Value="29.5" />
   <Arg Value="Hello World" />
  </Arguments>
</Function>
```

Now how can I call this function? Should I use `_asm` for this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did u mean `void CallFunction( void (*pFuncion)(void), std::string xmlFuncionDef)` ?

Comment: You ask about "how to call that function". But already the first part is not clear: How do you receive the pointer to that function? `void * pFuncion` is a pointer of type void, this is not a pointer to a function.

Comment: If your code should run on a specific architecture, then you can use inline assembly and push the arguments onto the stack and then call the function. But then your function is responsible to get the arguments off the stack in the correct order. Anyway your problem is not clearly defined. Be more specific and show some examples.

Comment: seems like you're trying to invent COM, SOAP web services, or similar architectures. That's rather a large task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, function pointers cannot have flexible arguments - you have to tell exactly what kind of parameters the function will receive. In your example:

```
void (*pFunc)(int,double,char*)
```

You could, of course, use the void* as a sole parameter and then treat that variability 
internally:

```
void (*pFunc)(void*)
```

BUT, I believe it would be an invite to a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way to do this is to make the bit of code which registers the function be template on its params and return type. You can then pull this apart and return a lambda which knows how to parse the XML and call the function. Really hacky proof of concept [which doesn't handle varargs (hardcoded to 2), uses strings instead of xml, assumes types are default constructible, doesn't handle refs or moves, and leaves a lot as an exercise to the reader] is:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template<class FIRST, class SECOND, class RETURN_TYPE>
std::function<RETURN_TYPE(std::string const&)> RegisterFunction(
    RETURN_TYPE(func)(FIRST f, SECOND s))
{
    auto copy = *func;
    return[copy](std::string const& str)->RETURN_TYPE
    {
        std::istringstream inStream(str);
        FIRST f;
        inStream >> f;
        if(inStream.fail())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't parse param one");
        }
        SECOND s;
        inStream >> s;
        if(inStream.fail())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't parse param two");
        }
        // can check if inStream is eof here for consistency
        return copy(f, s);
    };
}

std::string MyFunc(float f, std::string s)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "MyFunc called with float " << f << " and string " + s;
    return os.str();
}


int main()
{
    auto wrapper = RegisterFunction(MyFunc);

    // Now try to call it
    std::cout << wrapper("42.0 HelloWorld") << std::endl;

    // Try to call it with an invalid string
    try
    {
        std::cout << wrapper("This isn't the number you are looking for");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to call function" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
MyFunc called with float 42 and string HelloWorld
Failed to call function
```